# Efficient way to match column values with corresponding master table values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am importing Excel data in a stored procedure and storing the records in a temporary table. I want to validate values of few columns with corresponding values in master table.

I have added one more column to this temp table namely: Status, which holds either NULL or SKIP as value.

For instance, temporary table contains one column namely Location. Customers send pre-filled Excel sheet to us with all columns filled. On such column is this Location column. Often the spelling of location is not correct. If any location is say, New Jersey, the Excel sheet might contain spelling as New Jarsey.

I have a Location Master table which stores correct names of locations and IDs as well. I want to match location name in temp table with the corresponding location name in the master table. If location fails to match, I mark the Status column as SKIP in the temp table.

There are several columns in the temp table the values of which needs to be match with their corresponding master table values.

Is there any way to verify these column values in a more efficient and faster way? I want to match Locations row by row and similarly other column values.

Comment: Describe your real business requirement, **as well as** your broken attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly (actually showing some test data and expected results would help a lot), you could use either a series of `EXISTS` expressions or a series of outer joins. Here's an example using 2 different columns, each with a corresponding 'master table':

```
-- set up test data
declare @RawData table  (Location varchar(100) not null primary key, Country varchar(100) not null, Status char(4) null)
declare @LocationMaster table (Location varchar(100) not null primary key)
declare @CountryMaster table (Country varchar(100) not null primary key)

insert into @RawData (Location, Country) values ('New Jersey', 'USA'), ('New Jarsey', 'USA'), ('New York', 'USAA'), ('New Yoik', 'United States')
insert into @LocationMaster (Location) values ('New Jersey'), ('New York')
insert into @CountryMaster (Country) values ('USA')

-- option 1: EXISTS

update @RawData
set Status = 'SKIP'
from @RawData r
where 
    not exists (select * from @LocationMaster where Location = r.Location)
    or not exists (select * from @CountryMaster where Country = r.Country)

select * from @RawData

-- reset status
update @RawData set Status = null

-- option 2: OUTER JOIN

update @RawData
set Status = 'SKIP'
from 
    @RawData r
    left outer join @LocationMaster lm on lm.Location = r.Location
    left outer join @CountryMaster cm on cm.Country = r.Country
where
    lm.Location is null 
    or cm.Country is null

select * from @RawData
```

You can profile both plans in SSMS to determine which one is more efficient for your data set.